# Need to use bold tags in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have this form done it complete and working fine when the form is submitted the information is emailed to an email id but all the content is shown in plain text when it delivers I want that when the form information reaches the email id it it should the field names in bold.

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'abc@email.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.


if(
empty ($_POST['fullname']) ||
empty ($_POST['martialstatus']) ||
empty ($_POST['dateofbirth']) ||
empty ($_POST['email']) ||
empty ($_POST['telephone']) ||
empty ($_POST['cell']) ||
empty ($_POST['graduation']) ||
empty ($_POST['yearatt']) ||
empty ($_POST['department']) ||
empty ($_POST['program']) ||
empty ($_POST['permanentaddress']) ||
empty ($_POST['currentemp']) ||
empty ($_POST['designation']) ||
empty ($_POST['selfemp']) ||
empty ($_POST['officeemail']) ||
empty ($_POST['officetele']) ||
empty ($_POST['portfolio']) ||
empty ($_POST['membership']))

{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$martialstatus = $_POST['martialstatus'];
$dateofbirth = $_POST['dateofbirth'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$graduation = $_POST['graduation'];
$yearatt = $_POST['yearatt'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$program = $_POST['program'];
$permanentaddress = $_POST['permanentaddress'];
$currentemp = $_POST['currentemp'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$selfemp = $_POST['selfemp'];
$officeemail = $_POST['officeemail'];
$officetele = $_POST['officetele'];
$portfolio = $_POST['portfolio']; 
$membership = $_POST['membership'];



if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Membership Information: $fullname";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n  Personal Information \n\n 
    Name:                      $fullname \n 
    Martial Status:            $martialstatus \n 
    Date of Birth:             $dateofbirth \n 
    Email:                     $email \n 
    Telephone:                 $telephone \n 
    Cell:                      $cell \n 
    Year of Graduation:        $graduation \n 
    Years Attended:             $yearatt \n
    Department:                $department \n 
    Program Attended:          $program \n 
    Permanent Address:         $permanentaddress \n\n 
    Career Information \n\n 
    Currently Employeed with:  $currentemp \n 
    Designation:               $designation \n 
    Self Employeed:            $selfemp \n 
    Office Email:              $officeemail \n 
    Office Telephone:          $officetele \n 
    Portfolio:                 $portfolio \n\n 
    MemberShip \n\n 
    Type of MemberShip:        $membership \n\n "; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. You're trying to send an **HTML email**, not "use bold in PHP".

Comment: Your use of $_POST is a direct and wide open security hole. You _must_ filter the content of those variables.

Comment: I can't see any question here.

Answer (score 5):

Bold text can be done with an HTML email, set the content type header:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
```

Use the `<strong>` tag:

```
<strong>Name:</strong>                      $fullname <br />
```

Don't forget `\n` won't show a new line in an HTML email, you'll need to use `<br />`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to send the email in HTML format and change the respective line to

```
Email:                     <b>$email</b> \n
```

Comment: Using <b> is not recommended, use <strong> instead.

Comment: `<b>` and `<strong>` are not the same. I agree if we are talking about  semantic websites that might be read out aloud with screen readers where `<strong>` parts are read louder while `<b>` doesn't make a difference. In html emails, though, I prefer to still use the original bold tag as it will be rendered in bold by any email software I tested. This is not true for `<strong>`.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add headers, as specified on [Mail page documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

then use markup to compose your email

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the `Content-type` header, and add HTML tags to the email you're sending. So:

```
$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";
```

Also, you'll need to convert `\n` to HTML line breaks, so:

```
$email_body = nl2br($email_body);
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You headers must always end with `\r\n"

This is wrong

```
$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
```

It should be like this

```
$headers = "From: $myemail\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

You need to add HTML tags in your mail

Example

```
 Name:                      <strong>$fullname</strong><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of re-writing quite a bit, mostly because there is so much repetition, and a huge security issue.

One could make several further improvements on this as well, but that's left as an exercise to the reader.

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'abc@email.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.

$fields = array(
    'fullname' => 'Name',
    'martialstatus' => 'Martial Status',
    'dateofbirth' => 'Date of Birth',
    'email' => 'Email',
    'telephone' => 'Telephone',
    'cell' => 'Cell',
    'graduation' => 'Year of Graduation',
    'yearatt' => 'Years Attended',
    'department' => 'Department',
    'program' => 'Program Attended',
    'permanentaddress' => 'Permanent Address',
    'currentemp' => 'Currently Employeed with',
    'designation' => 'Designation',
    'selfemp' => 'Self Employeed',
    'officeemail' => 'Office Email',
    'officetele' => 'Office Telephone',
    'portfolio' => 'Portfolio',
    'membership' => 'Type of MemberShip',
);

// Don't allow HTML in form.
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
}

$missing_fields = array_diff_assoc($fields, $_POST);

if (count($missing_fields) > 0) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = 'Membership Information: ' . $_POST['fullname'];
    $email_body = 'You have received a new message. Here are the details:<br />  Personal Information <br/ ><br/ >';
    foreach (array('fullname', 'martialstatus', 'dateofbirth', 'email', 'telephone', 'cell', 'graduation', 'yearatt', 'department', 'program', 'permanentaddress') as $key) {
      $email_body .= $fields[$key] . ': <strong>' . $_POST[$key] . "</strong><br />";
    }

    $email_body .= "Career Information <br /><br />";

    foreach (array('currentemp', 'designation', 'selfemp', 'officeemail', 'officetele', 'portfolio') as $key) {
      $email_body .= $fields[$key] . ': <strong>' . $_POST[$key] . "</strong><br />";
    }

    $email_body .= "MemberShip <br /><br />";

    foreach (array('membership') as $key) {
      $email_body .= $fields[$key] . ': <strong>' . $_POST[$key] . "</strong><br />";
    }

    $headers = "From: $myemail\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $myemail\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```