# Using HTML code in PHP email

Tags: php, html, email

Is there any way I can put HTML code in Email message and Auto Response message? When I'm trying the email output it with HTML code too.

```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $mailto = 'info@website.com';
  $mailfrom = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : $mailto;
  $subject = 'Email Subject';
  $message = 'Hello, Email message...'; // Want to try something like '<Strong>Hello</strong> Email message...'
  $success_url = './success.php';
  $error_url = './failed.php';
  $error = '';
  $autoresponder_from = 'noreply@website.com';
  $autoresponder_subject = 'Auto Response Subject';
  $autoresponder_message = 'Hello John, Thank you.'; // Want to try something like '<Strong>Hello John</strong> Thank you.'
```

Comment: Yes, just use proper headers for HTML. `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` [**Consult the PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Don't send HTML formatted email without a plain text alternative. Don't use ISO-8855 this century.

Comment: PHP's built-in `mail()` functions sucks for anything complex like HTML emails. Consider using a decent mailer class such as PHPMailer which will make things easy for you.

Comment: Take a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329055/need-to-use-bold-tags-in-php?answertab=votes#10329132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the correct header for html emails

have a look at Example #4: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

**PHP**

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Don't forget to add a plain copy of your message

Comment: "Don't forget to add a plain copy of your message" — and the first thing you do to achieve that is **not** say `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: @Quentin Well I learned something more today; "noted & filed".